# Can't login to paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal

I am trying to login with a business test account at paypal sandbox it keeps redirecting to this URL https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-submit 
and the page contains one line saying "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features" 
with "PayPal Sandbox" being an anchor pointing to developer.paypal.com and when I click on it I go to the developer site which I am already logged in at with a live paypal account.

Answer (score 30):

This is how you get access to your test account's page:

1. Go to [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com)
2. Go to [Applications](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications)
3. Click on [Sandbox accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts)
4. Choose Log In with PayPal (use your regular account - not the Sandbox one)
5. (Optional) Import your old accounts from your former Sandbox account after the redirect to the accounts page
6. Click on the account you want to log in to
7. Choose "Sandbox site"
8. Log in to that site using your test account

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, because in the import data option the textbox of sandbox email doesn't accept the email I enter, it keeps saying "Enter a valid email address" and the mail am entering is valid, it's the email I used before for creating the developer account on the old site and which I received the activation mail on.It seems that this text box accepts only emails which are xxx@hotmail xxx@yahoo xxx@gmail etc and my email is xxx@companyname.net. This is very strange and frustrating too.

Comment: Can you send an email to developer at paypal dot com with your sandbox email? We'll check if there is an "issue" with our email validation. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll send an email.

Comment: I am also having problem integrating the new paypal. I have successfully imported my old test account.
When I go to sandbox site and login using my test account, its not successfull. Check this screenshot what it looks http://screencast.com/t/qqvioagkH5

Don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Also, when I create a new test account using myemail@mydomain.com and click the profile, I see the status as "Unverified" but If I will create using myemail@gmail.com, it shows "Verified". Do you have any idea what is happening?

Comment: I had the same problem. Fixed it by removing the dot in the section before the @, so I used myname@domain.com, which worked, instead of my.name@domain.com, which didn't work. @PayPal_Tim can this be fixed? It's rubbish!

Comment: @greg84 we're working on fixing this - promised!

Comment: @PayPal_Tim, It's Apr 11, when is going to be fixed?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem as Yasmine discussed above.Even after entering my valid email id I am unable to login to my developer account.Earlier it used to work fine.The new developer site is too confusing.I am a non US user.

Comment: @Tim Hi tim I have been facing a problem with paypal sandbox not really sure how to get with this but I can't get it to work here, have been clearing my cache alot of times but the epic "This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address." just won't go away also even deleting previously created sandbox emails won't work, I'm not sure where to go with this but I cannot proceed with my developments on our store with this unidentified issue getting along the way!

Comment: The links are taking me to 404

Comment: The https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications redirects you to a nice *Secure Connection Failed* page. But the fancy green badge in the address bar is there. It takes a lot of skills to do that, seriously. @Alain Goldman retardpal?

Comment: outdated. links are 404.