# Is it mandatory to have paypal account to access existing sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have an existing sandbox account where I have generated buttons for one of my client.
But now I cannot login to my sandbox account.

I have read this thread

[Can't login to paypal sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461110/cant-login-to-paypal-sandbox)

1. Go to developer.paypal.com
2. Go to Applications
3. Click on Sandbox accounts
4. Choose Log In with PayPal (use your regular account - not the Sandbox one)
   (Optional) Import your old accounts from your former Sandbox account after the redirect to the accounts page
5. Click on the account you want to log in to
   Choose "Sandbox site"
   Log in to that site using your test account

I have not got this and I don't have the **regular account** on paypal.

Anybody can help me to get my existing sandbox account?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to login with your PayPal account for the new sandbox of PayPal.

You can then import all your old sandbox accounts into new sandbox account, using old sandbox credentials

Comment: So I need to create new PayPal account and then I am able to import my old sandbox account, is this right?

Comment: Yes, just create an account in PayPal, you can skip adding bank account into PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to create a regular Paypal account.
- Go to developer.paypal.com and log in with the new account.
- Go to Applications > Sandbox account > import sandbox accounts.
- Your old sandbox accounts will be imported.