# How do I log into PayPal Sandbox account?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, paypal, e-commerce

They changed the menu, I can't find how to log into SandBox Account, the old steps mentioned here [Can't login to paypal sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461110/cant-login-to-paypal-sandbox) dont work

Can someone please provide step by step instructions how to log into sandbox account and see my payments?

Also can I test the account by sending money from real CC to sandbox credentials? Is that how it's supposed to work? I don't completely understand what sandbox is for, is it for buying or for selling?

Answer (score 0):

Manage Sandbox Accounts in [the Developer Dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts).

Log in to one at [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com)